# How to connect Redis desktop manager to digital ocean ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, redis, virtual-machine, digital-ocean, ubuntu-server

I have deployed my nodejs app on digital ocean droplet Ubuntu server, And install redis-server on it and working perfectly.

```
root@droovia:~/droovia.com# sudo systemctl status redis
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-10-09 06:44:33 UTC; 44min ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
 Main PID: 4677 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─4677 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Oct 09 06:44:33 droovia systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Oct 09 06:44:33 droovia systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Oct 09 06:44:33 droovia systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

And now I need to connect Redis from droplet ubuntu server to my computer [desktop Redis manager](https://electronjs.org/apps/p3x-redis-ui)

I allow the port 6379 with `sudo ufw allow 6379`

```
root@droovia:~/droovia.com# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
4000                       DENY        Anywhere                  
6379                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
4000 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
6379 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And tried to connect with Redis desktop manager by entering digital ocean droplet IP ###.##.###.### and Redis port

[image]

Do I miss anything in the above steps

Comment: You have to look for bindIP in config file for accepting other connections

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to be bound to `0.0.0.0` as `127.0.0.1` is the local loopback for local-only traffic.

In your `redis.conf` set:

`bind 127.0.0.1`

to

`bind 0.0.0.0`

I'd definitely think carefully about opening your Redis server up to public traffic though.

Comment: how can I connect only to my machine?